# Mailserver and MX records in Cloudflare

Tags: postfix, email-server, mx-record

I built my own mail server using postfix/dovecot in CentOS 6, this is my postconf -n results:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relay_domains =
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

I've tried using telnet to test my emails and I do get them in the /home/user/Maildir/new folder.

I assume everything is OK with the mail server, so I went ahead and added MX records to my DNS settings.

This is the first time I've used Cloudflare's free DNS service, and I admit to not being the most knowledgeable person when it comes to this, but I added a couple of records in there:

- **MX** - @ => mail.example.com
- **A** - mail.example.com => My VPS ip (where the mail server is located)

The MX record seems to be in place, a quick "dig MX example.com" does wield a result. The problem now is... even though I created the record as **mail.example.com**, the actual entry as seen via dig is **dc-8c1937cd-mail.example.com.**, a string seems to have been appended to the DNS record.

I've since tried sending email from an outside source (not telnet) without success. Do I need to reconfigure postfix and set myhostname as dc-8c1937cd-mail.example.com.? Am I missing something here in the grander scheme of DNS or is this just the way Cloudflare operates? Could my mailserver not be configured correctly? (logs from my telnet tests look fine)

Comment: You say that the `MX` record refers to `dc-8c1937cd-mail.example.com`. Does that name resolve?

Comment: Yes, it is resolving to the IP where my mail server is located.

Comment: What happened to the mail you tried to send yourself?

Comment: Is it possible to connect to that IP on 25/tcp? (No firewall in the way or something like that?)

Comment: Yes, I can connect just fine, the IP is 198.91.92.162 and the domain for this case is jdlferreira.com. I've now tried to change the myhostname var to match the MX record and restarted postfix, again, telnet tests seem fine, but trying to send emails through gmail and the likes doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Michael Hampton, the mail ca be found in the /home/user/Maildir/new dir, the logs show no errors whatsoever, I was under the impression emails could be found in /var/mail/user or /var/spool/mail/user, but there are no records there.

Comment: So the mail _was_ delivered successfully. It just isn't where you thought it would be. That's a totally separate question to "is my DNS right?"

Comment: Fwiw, I get 'connection refused' if I connect to 198.91.92.162 port 25. However, if you had it working I suppose you are just making some changes at the moment(?)

Comment: Ah. Well. I am sort of "server-stupid". Even after following Michaels advice I'm yet to have success. So now it looks like my DNS settings are OK. Hakan, I simply followed the instructions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798772/postfix-its-installed-but-how-do-i-test to test out postfix and assumed everything was ok after receiving my email. Do I need to configure postfix in any other way to allow emails from the outside?

Comment: I'd guess firewall if you are saying that `telnet 198.91.92.162 25` works locally. You can use `sudo system-config-firewall-tui` on RHEL/Centos.

Comment: Issue was inet_interfaces=localhost (needs to be all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was `inet_interfaces = localhost`, causing postfix only to listen port 25 locally, setting it to `inet_interfaces = all` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the CloudFlare DNS settings, make sure that you have a "gray" cloud for the `mail` A record, in order for connections to that host to bypass CloudFlare and go to your mail server directly.

Beyond that, your DNS seems to be in a workable configuration, and you are (by your own admission) receiving mail successfully.

Comment: Good catch on "gray" cloud thing, I missed that entirely.

Answer (score -1):

next step would be to check into your server and check /var/log/maillog (postfix) and perhaps the dovecot log.

If u are sending an email to yourself for testing u should see the connection in the postfix log, with errors if any.

If the mail get thru postfix its taken by the local handler such as per example dovecot

Comment: The question has an accepted answer. Please read those before posting something on an old question.